# How to apply function to only certain array elements?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have an array `x` and I want to apply a function `f` to every item in the matrix that meets some condition. Does Numpy offer a mechanism to make this easy?

Here's an example. My matrix `x` is supposed to contain only elements in the exclusive range `(0, 1)`. However, due to rounding errors, some elements can be equal to `0` or `1`. For every element in `x` that is exactly `0` I want to add `epsilon` and for every element that is exactly `1` I want to subtract `epsilon`.

**Edit:** (This edit was made after I had accepted [askewchan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15303168/627005).) Another way to do this is to use [`numpy.clip`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
a = np.array([0,.1,.5,1])
epsilon = 1e-5
a[a==0] += epsilon
a[a==1] += -epsilon
```

The reason this works is that `a==0` returns a boolean array, just like what [Валера Горбунов](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2149700/) referred to in their answer:

```
In : a==0
Out: array([True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Then you're using that array as an index to `a`, which exposes the elements where `True` but not where `False`.  There's a lot that you can do with this, see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: No problem.  I fixed it to make epsilon tiny (`1e-5`) not huge (`1e5`).

Answer (score 3):

Sorry this isn't more concrete, but you could create a Boolean array that has a TRUE value for every position that meets your condition and FALSE for those that don't.

For something like [0, 1, 0, 0] when testing for 1 you will get an array [FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE].  In which case you can do [0, 1, 0, 0] - (epsilon)[FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE] and leave the 0 values unaffected.

[Boolean Array Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525921/numpy-array-boolean-to-binary)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map()` as documented at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#functional-programming-tools:

```
def applyEpsilon(value):
    myEpsilon = 0.001
    if value == 0:
        return myEpsilon
    elif value == 1:
        return 1-myEpsilon
    return value

inputList = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.99, 1]
print map(applyEpsilon, inputList)
```

Yields:

```
[0.001, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.99, 0.999]
```

Comment: One of the advantages of numpy arrays is that it doesn't use python loops, which could be slow if the list is very long.